# Spring Integration JMS message driven channel adapter stops picking message after certain interval of time

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using spring integration to read message from TIBCO EMS queue using jms-int:message-driven-channel-adapter. I am facing issue : After certain interval of time say 5-10 hours(occurs at random interval), jms channel adapter stops picking the message even if there is message in the jms queue

Below is my spring integration context :

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${sessionCacheSize}"/>
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="${cacheProducers}"/>
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="${cacheConsumers}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsQueue" class="${queueClassName}">
    <constructor-arg value="${jmsQueue}" />
</bean>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="jmsMessageDrivenAdapter" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" channel="jmsListenerChannel" destination="jmsQueue"
    error-channel="integrationErrorChannel" max-concurrent-consumers="${maxConcurrentConsumers}" auto-startup="${jms.autostart}"/>
```

I have feature to start/stop jmsMessageDrivenAdapter, and the adapter can be started/stopped anytime while it is picking messages but at this point, start/stop feature does not works too. Please suggest !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Spring Integration jms message driven channel adapter fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018207/spring-integration-jms-message-driven-channel-adapter-fails) (but a different contributor, so I'll answer again here)...

This is generally caused by some component in the downstream flow hanging the container thread uninterruptibly (e.g. reading from a socket with no timeout, where no data arrives).

To diagnose, take a thread dump (e.g. jstack ) when the hang occurs, to find out what the listener container threads are doing.